# What is the collective name for Bitcoin, Namecoin, etc?

Tags: terminology, standard

Is there some standard term to describe all Bitcoin-like internet currencies, like Solidcoin, Namecoin and so forth? Like "currency" is to dollar, euro, yen, etc?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

distributed digital currency, or distributed digital crypto-currency. the "distributed" bit is a key issue - anyone can make a centralized digital currency, even with crypto thrown in.

Comment: We need some shorter name for that.

Comment: The "digital" part is probably unnecessary, as there is few uses for non-digital crypto-currencies.

Comment: indeed probably digital can be dropped... that said, what's the goal here? "the shortest name" or "the most accurate name" ?

Comment: Probably the shortest of the names which are accurate, that is cover all the -coins without using a qualifier that doesn't add any information.

Comment: Distributed != decentralized.

Mintchip, for instance, is close as it is distributed (multiple issuers), but it is not in the same league as bitcoin because the rules on it are centrally controlled.

Answer (score 9):

It's called crypto-currency, [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypto-currency).

Comment: As there are no crypto-currencies that are not decentralized, this is probably the shortest of the proper terms we can use so far, but that might change in the future to "distributed crypto-currency", as pointer out by nanotube.

Comment: "As there are no crypto-currencies that are not decentralized" <- this is false. see, e.g., loom.cc.

Answer (score 1):

I use "chain currencies". There are precedents for crypto currencies. OT currencies are also crypto-currencies.
Ripple IOUs use cryptoGraphy in the distributed protocol too. The uniqueness is definitely in the block chain. 
I often refer to them as just "coins" since most of them are called SomethingCoin.

Answer (score -1):

I think crypto-currency is the good term.

But personnally I tend to use digital currency because crypto can scare some users.